# Where to store possibly sensitive but unimportant information

Tags: database, database-design, domain-driven-design, data-modeling

I am working on an app which touches sensitive information, like money.
We have some calculators, and we want to prefill the values with whatever the user has entered last. Apart from increasing UX, we don't need those. But we cannot store it in web storage or cookie because of security.

We have

- a JS frontend,
- an API Gateway backend that is supposed to be "stupid", so it only handles authentication and sending messages to to corresponding services
- some services that actually care about the business logic

These possibilities come to mind and I cannot decide which I should do (and foremost: why)

- Add a table in backend, that is a catch all for implementing cookie-like functionality in backend
- Add a specific table in the service it fits the most
- Use a key value store in backend (don't know about this, a coworker put it out there)

Answer (score 0):

As i read your requirements it seams that this is kind of a defaulting including some business logic (stupid or smart). Personally i see defaulting as part of business logic and based on this it's part of the service which cares about this functionality.

> Add a table in backend, that is a catch all for implementing cookie-like functionality in backend

This sounds like a generic solution for a pretty generic requirement. what do you wanna achieve with this?

> Add a specific table in the service it fits the most

Sounds reasonable especially because you put it there where it belongs. Does it have to be a table? why not calculate or copy the values on runtime?

> Use a key value store in backend (don't know about this, a coworker put it out there)

This is maybe a technological decision but first you need a design decision.